MySQL loading data from file fails with permission denied error
When I try to load data to a table, I get the following error:
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/table.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE mytable
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/home/user/table.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Since I am doing this on the MySQL server itself and logging in remotely, I don't think I need to use LOCAL INFILE.
I don't have the secure_file_priv set, so the file should be accessible.
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv |       |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

And the permissions for this specific file should allow reading by everyone
$ ls -lh table.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 9.3K Dec 20 22:12 table.txt
$ stat table.txt 
  File: table.txt
  Size: 9508            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 252,0   Inode: 1593546     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1003/  user)   Gid: ( 1004/  user)
Access: 2024-12-22 08:33:39.123656806 -0500
Modify: 2024-12-20 22:12:36.974314605 -0500
Change: 2024-12-22 08:59:47.186353993 -0500
 Birth: 2024-12-20 22:12:36.920314628 -0500


I tried copying the file to /tmp directory and using that path to load but that did not work either. I also tried changing the file permissions and make it read, write and executable by everyone. That did not help either.
I am at a loss as to what is preventing the load from happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT 1
I ran strace as suggested by @Ergest Basha and here's what I see:
sudo strace -f -p $(pgrep mysqld) 2>&1 | grep 'table.txt' 
[pid 978383] readlink("/home/user/table.txt", 0x707ee69fb930, 1023) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 978383] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/user/table.txt", 0x707ee69fc560, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)


Why not enable secure_file_priv and set it to /var/lib/mysql-files/

Mainly for convenience. But now I am reconsidering that. Currently, the permissions for that directory are very restrictive. Is it okay to grant everyone permission to read+write to that directory?

On a parallel terminal use strace -f -p $(pgrep mysqld) 2>&1 | grep table.txt and see the output , it will shows a permission error. Why not enable secure_file_priv and set it to /var/lib/mysql-files/ , then use LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/table.txt' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;. Why going through a lot of file/directory permission changes ?

MySQL
Version: 8.0.40-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
By default MySQL restricts access to /home.
The steps I followed to re-create your issue.
Setting secure_file_priv to empty under mysqld section on mysqld.conf
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = ""

Created table.txt with the following content
root@dbs:~# cat /home/e.basha/table.txt
id,col1
1,2

After running LOAD DATA INFILE command I received the same Permission denied error from /home and /tmp directories
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/e.basha/table.txt' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/home/e.basha/table.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/table.txt' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/table.txt' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

I checked if the user running MySQL can access /home/e.basha/table.txt
root@dbs:~# sudo -u mysql cat /home/e.basha/table.txt
cat: /home/e.basha/table.txt: Permission denied

I gave the following permissions , now the user can access the file, but the LOAD DATA INFILE command still gave the same error
root@dbs:~# chmod 755 /home
root@dbs:~# chmod 755 /home/e.basha
root@dbs:~# sudo -u mysql cat /home/e.basha/table.txt
id,col1
1,2root@dbs:~#

I disabled AppArmor(I do not recommend doing so, I did just for testing purposes) and the command worked fine. So the issue is on the Apparmor restriction.
root@dbs:~# aa-disable /usr/sbin/mysqld
Disabling /usr/sbin/mysqld.

I edited /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and added /home/e.basha/* r, after the line containing /var/lib/mysql-files/** rwk, then reload and activate again apparmorand everything worked fine.
root@dbs:~# nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
#Allow data files dir access
  /var/lib/mysql-files/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql-files/** rwk,
  /home/e.basha/* r,


root@dbs:~# apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
root@dbs:~# aa-enforce /usr/sbin/mysqld


MariaDB
For future readers if facing the same issue on MariaDB

MariaDB's systemd unit file restricts access to /home, /root, and
/run/user by default. This restriction can be overridden by setting
the ProtectHome option to false for the MariaDB systemd service. This
is done by creating a "drop-in" directory
/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/ and in it a file with a .conf
suffix that contains the ProtectHome=false directive.

Edit mariadb.service by using systemctl edit mariadb.service and add the following lines
[Service]
ProtectHome=false

at the start of the files before the following line
### Lines below this comment will be discarded


My suggestion
I suggest using secure_file_priv , default configuration  /var/lib/mysql-files/ since using a designated directory is generally better for security and maintainability. Using secure_file_priv* and restricting file operations to /var/lib/mysql-files/ is a more secure, manageable, and efficient approach

Thanks, after setting secure_file_priv to default, the problem is with the permissions for /var/lib/mysql-files/. I see the following. I am in mysql group and the directory has r+w permissions for everyone, but I can't still copy the file to that directory unless I am root
sgbb@r730xd01:~$ groups sgbb sudo mysql sgbb@r730xd01:~$ ls -lhd /var/lib/mysql-files/ drwxrw-rw- 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Dec 22 08:33 /var/lib/mysql-files/ sgbb@r730xd01:~$ cp ~/table.txt /var/lib/mysql-files/ cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/mysql-files/table.txt': Permission denied 

@vkkodali and if you use sudo cp ~/table.txt /var/lib/mysql-files/ ? Anyway this is no more related to MySQL.

Yes, sudo cp ~/table.txt /var/lib/mysql-files/ works. But I would like to not have to run this as root every time I need to load data.

@vkkodali add your user to the sudoers, something like sudo adduser yourUser --force-badname , if it throws an error related to the user name
